# Dax to find previous day sale based on data availability

Tags: sql-server, dax, ssas-tabular, msbi

I have created one measure in SSAS tabular called "Yesterday Sales by using max(date)-1", with this I am getting blanks if data is not present for max(date)-1. how to get the sales for the next available date.

for Example, my max(date) is 2019-11-25 and before that I have data for 2019-11-22. I don't have data for 23rd and 24th, in this case, I want to show "yesterday sales" for 2019-11-22. can you help to achieve this through Dax?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked up LASTNONBLANK()?

https://exceleratorbi.com.au/lastnonblank-explained/

http://sqljason.com/2012/06/lastnonempty-in-tabular-mode-part-1.html

Comment: yes, but it will return lastnoblank value, so if my data is till 2019-11-25, this function returns the date 2019-11-25 but I don't have data for 23rd and 24th, I want to find those dates.